# Unobserved Component Model in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels

I want to perofrm UCM for Multivarate Data in Python in with my dependent variables as lets say Sales and Independent variable as Promo_Var1,Promo_Var2, Promo_Var3.

Can we do something like this below

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.tsa.UnobservedComponents(df['Sales'],df['Promo_Var1','Promo_Var2','Promo_Var3']).fit()
```

Comment: see `exog` keyword in http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.structural.UnobservedComponents.html

Comment: When i am predicting the values of future with future exog it is still giving me sales of past endog where i generated the  model

Comment: You need to provide more information, preferably a full minimum working example, otherwise we don't know what you did.